# Coaxial cables for cable tv transmission and normal wires for electricity transmission

Tags: electromagnetism

Why are coaxial cables used for cable tv transmission and normal wires used for electricity transmission?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about wiring standards and not physics.

Comment: @KyleKanos no, it's not a standard.  It is in fact based on physics

Comment: @CarlWitthoft: sure *some* aspect of it is based on physics, but the reasons for the chosen standards are based on things *not* physics.

Comment: The question has sufficient physics and I don't see any reason to call it off-topic.

Comment: I agree with Karl Witthoft. The choice of wiring geometry is always dictated by physics. Coaxial cables weren't just invented by a techno-bureaucrat who thought it would be fun to force people by decree to using a central wire in a conducting pipe. It's one of a few geometries that works for this purpose. Twisted pairs, as used in ethernet cables would be another, but twisted pairs require differential drivers and receivers, which were not easily done at the time coax came into use. Today they are the standard method for the physically identical purpose, though.

Comment: @KyleKanos I would ask that you please leave the close-voting of questions like to this to those of us who actually practice experimental physics. We've been through this engineering issue before and I thought we had come to an agreement. The trigger happy close voting on stuff like this is probably why it's so hard for people like me to get important experimental questions answered; you guys scare off all the experimentalists.

Comment: @CuriousOne Note that you can vote to reopen this question.

Comment: @DanielSank: Not necessary. Carl Witthoft has given a valid answer IMHO. One could refine it, of course, but I am not sure it would help the OP much and we had similar questions about the physics of cables before.

Comment: @DanielSank: What physics experiment deals with TV transmissions?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it shows no effort.

Comment: @KyleKanos - Marconi, Tesla, and Hertz didn't do any physics experiments?

Answer (score 4):

The reason has to do with the frequency of the transmitted electricity and thus the wavelength of the associated E-M field.   60 or 50 or 240 Hz power transmission is close enough to DC that the current is carried along the wire (and the return wire).  The RF frequencies in cable tv signals are getting "close" to microwave frequencies, so you can support the field in the space between the carrier and the shield -- not to mention that the return path (shield) protects the RF signal from any external interference.  RF interference on power lines is simply rejected with filters here and there, but the coax cable tv is sending *information* in the RF, rather than simply sending power.

If you get a bit higher in frequency, the signal can in fact be sent without the central conductor at all;  the EM field propagating inside a hollow conducting shield.

Comment: This answer explains that higher frequencies *can* travel in coax, but it doesn't say why you *cannot* send high frequency signals on a normal wire. I would think the latter is a critical part of the question.

Comment: @DanielSank    Your comment motivates my  comment although I realize it is months later.  "...doesn't say why you cannot send high frequency signals on a normal wire" seems to suggest that there must be a reason why this should or can't be done.  Well, I send HF signals on normal #16 gauge copper-clad steel wire all the time and it works much better than using Coax.  I do this every single day in transmitting signals over the air on the 80/40/30 meter bands  on a 136 foot long Dipole Antenna 70 feet up in the air.

Comment: @K7PEH 30 meters is not "high frequency" to me :-)

Comment: @DanielSank There are precise definitions of the various segments of the RF spectrum.  HF (High Frequency) is from 3 MHz to 30 MHz.  Above HF is VHF (Very High Frequency) which ranges from 30 MHz to 300 MHz.  Above VHF is UHF and so on.  Below HF is MF (Medium Frequency) which ranges from 300 KHz to 3 MHz and several more segments below that.  Now, HF may not be high to you but to me HF is precisely 3 to 30 MHz!

Comment: @DanielSank By the way, those RF spectrum names (HF, VHF, etc.) are defined as international standards both by ITU and IEEE (probably other standards bodies as well).